# Splitter for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best way to enable the user to dynamically change the width of columns of a Twitter Bootstrap styled page?

For instance, to add a vertical divider/splitter in the following example?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6 resizeMe">Left</div>
        <div class="span6 resizeMe">Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [jQuery UI .resizable()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/), [jQuery Splitter Plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/), [jQuery Layout Plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) - but I am wondering whether there is a specific solution for bootstrap? (or one that will work together with it particularly well)

Comment: According to this [answer on the maillist](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-ui-layout/2E90WQYIzcU) there arenot many problems when combining jQuery Layout and Twitter bootstrap.

Comment: FYI JQuery Splitter plugin is now deprecated (incompatible with jQuery > 1.8)

Comment: there is  [another jquery splitter here](https://github.com/vorburger/jquery.splitter), which appears to still work with jQuery 1.10.2

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind it not being animated or dynamically adjustable, here's something I've been working on similar to this with Bootstrap (I'm using 2.1.0, but this should work in any 2.x versions):

Set up a button group:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <a href="##" rel="tooltip" title="Make the Directories side dominant" class="btn btn-mini" data-action="dirDom" data-placement="left"><i class="icon icon-indent-left"></i></a>
        <a href="##" rel="tooltip" title="Make both sides equal" class="btn btn-mini" data-placement="left" data-action="equality"><i class="icon icon-resize-horizontal"></i></a>
        <a href="##" rel="tooltip" title="Make the Documents side dominant" class="btn btn-mini" data-placement="left" data-action="fileDom"><i class="icon icon-indent-right"></i></a>
        </div>
```

Now, here's the JQuery magic:

```
$(function(){
$('a[data-action="dirDom"]').click(function (){
    $("#dirList").css('display','inline').removeAttr('class').addClass("span12");
    $("#fileList").removeAttr('class').css("display","none");

});
$('a[data-action="equality"]').click(function (){
    $("#dirList").css('display','inline').removeAttr('class').addClass("span6");
    $("#fileList").css('display','inline').removeAttr('class').addClass("span6");
});
$('a[data-action="fileDom"]').click(function (){
    $("#fileList").css('display','inline').removeAttr('class').addClass("span12");
    $("#dirList").removeAttr('class').css("display","none");
});
```

});

I've been trying to animate it, but haven't had much luck, but this works in terms of making one size fully visible, then the left side fully visible, and finally back to equal sizes. I'm sure better JQuery could be written, but hey, it's a first draft ;)

Comment: I've attempted to try out your approach in a live demo: http://jsbin.com/iwekuk/1/ - is that what you had in mind? ... I  still miss the dynamic slider/divider like for instance used by the [jQuery Splitter plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/)!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a bootstrap way currently, however you can add a class to one of your divs which puts `border-left:1px solid #EEE` or `border-right:1px solid #EEE`. The only problem with this solution is your combined span of 12 will now be more than the normal span12 width by 1px and it will push one of the divs to the next line. If it is acceptable to do so you can fix this by making the second div only span5 so your total is span11 + 1px.

It would be nice if bootstrap had a class for this that did not interfere with the normal grid system.

Comment: Which JS framework would you then use to 'move' the splitter?

Answer (score 0):

If looking to create left menu bar which can be resized by dragging, jsplitter might be a good fit - https://jsplitter.dilif.com/p/jsplitter/

Live examples - https://jsplitter.dilif.com/p/jsplitter/doc/3/3/working-examples/

It has two options -

- First one works with divs placed in flex box
- Second works on divs positioned with left one as "position:fixed;width:X;" and right one as "margin-left:X". This is the way side menu's are added in most websites.